# Unauthorized Text to Speech Watson IBM

Tags: javascript, jquery, reconhecimento-de-voz, watson

Estou com um problema ao tentar fazer uma requisição através da api text-to-speech, ao tentar fazer a requisição ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized"
}
```

***Meu código JS***

```
$(function () {

    $("#btnPOst").click(function () {

        var username= "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX";  
        var password = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX";
        var request = $("#text-to-speech input[name=speech-text]").val();

        var url = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_MichaelVoice&accept=audio/wav&text=" + request;


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'audio/wav',
            'Authorization': ("Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password))
        },

        success: function (content) {
            alert('ok');
        },

    });

    $("#speech").attr("src", url)[0].play();

    });
});
```

***Meu código HTML***

```
<input type="text" name="speech-text" TextMode="MultiLine" />
<input type="button" id="btnPOst" value="Play" />
<audio id="speech" autoplay preload="auto" autobuffer controls class="audio"></audio>
```

Comment: O HTTP Status Code `401 - Unauthorized` significa exatamente o que parece, não-autorizado. Provavelmente a API necessita de algum token ou password que você não está passado ou está passando incorretamente.

Comment: @fernandosavio então vi na documentação e achei esse comando em curl: `curl -X GET -u "apikey:{apikey}" --output hello_world.wav "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?accept=audio%2Fwav&amp;text=Hello%20world&amp;voice=en-US_AllisonVoice"`, o que seria esse -u na requição?

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nesse link](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=curl+-X+GET+-u+%22apikey%3A%7Bapikey%7D%22+--output+hello_world.wav+%22https%3A%2F%2Fstream.watsonplatform.net%2Ftext-to-speech%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fsynthesize%3Faccept%3Daudio%252Fwav%26amp%3Btext%3DHello%2520world%26amp%3Bvoice%3Den-US_AllisonVoice%22). Esse site é bom para explicar comandos.

Comment: O erro continua o mesmo Unauthorized

Comment: [Docs](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/curl.html?curl#synthesize). Na documentação você precisa usar uma APIKey, você gerou e está usando ela? Não e por usuário/senha. E aconselho a usar o método [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) no `request`antes de jogar na string.

Comment: @fernandosavio usar a APIKey no próprio Authorization? ou seja a ficaria assim:  `'Authorization':'MINHA API KEY'`?